# CollectionView and rotation problems

Tags: uiwebview, uicollectionview, mpmovieplayercontroller

I have a modal form sheet view that pops over a `UICollectionView`. In that modal view, I have a `MPMoviePlayerController` embedded in a `UIWebView`. If you make the movie player go full screen and then you rotate it, the CollectionView doesn't rotate with it. See, when I rotate the view when the video is not full screen, I can see the CollectionView update the cell positioning behind the view. However, it doesn't do that when the video is playing. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: `MPMoviePlayerController` embedded in a `UIWebView`? Show us that code.

Comment: In ViewDidLoad: NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:
                  self.videoURL];
    _moviePlayer =  [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [[_moviePlayer view] setFrame:[webView bounds]];
[webView addSubview:[_moviePlayer view]];
    [_moviePlayer play];

Answer (score 0):

In ViewDidLoad:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: self.videoURL];           
_moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url]; 
[[_moviePlayer view] setFrame:[webView bounds]]; 
[webView addSubview:[_moviePlayer view]]; [_moviePlayer play];
```